# What should I plug in first, my voltage regulator or UPS and why?

Tags: desktop-computer, ups, wiring

My UPS has the following specs:

```
INVO brand 
Model : 1500VA
Input :220Va,c50/60hz
output:220Va,c50/60hz
Capacity:1500VA,900W
```

My AVR has the following specs:

```
KEBO brand
HDR-2000VA
Input :14-260
Output 220-50/60 hz
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make any difference for the equipment powered by them:
Any decent UPS is also a voltage regulator, because it creates a regulated output, regardless of what the input is doing (of course, presuming the UPS battery has been charged).

Unless your mains voltage fluctuates wildly (drops too much below/above the input specs of the UPS regularly), in which case you put the regulator before the UPS and plug the regulator into the mains first. This takes a lot of strain of the UPS and prevents it from being worn out prematurely.

**PLEASE NOTE:** If your mains power is so bad that you need a separate regulator have an electrician look at it immediately. For house-wiring this isn't acceptable. (In industrial buildings heavy duty equipment may cause such issues, but it still isn't nice and usually a sign the power-grid is under too much strain.)

Comment: Plenty of commercial-grade UPS devices have bypass circuitry for high efficiency operation and do not force conversion all the time (best case, 90-95% efficiency). Smaller units may combine backup power and line regulation, but most medium and larger units do not include transient voltage protection. This is not good general advice.

Comment: @AndrewDomaszek I know, believe me I know... I deal with modular UPS systems in the 1-10 MVA range, which we specifically tailor to various deployments.  But I didn't want to overcomplicate things in my answer and as he was asking about a 1500VA unit (AKA shoebox UPS) this was most definitely in the small unit area.

Answer (score 0):

The ups should be plugged into the voltage regulator.

https://www.sweetwater.com/insync/power-conditioner-voltage-regulator-ups-differences-explained/

Why?

Most of the change in line voltage will come from the external source, normally the power company.  This will also protect your UPS by providing the correct line voltage.